Should a colorscheme that queries `background` set `background&`?
I recently converted the :highlight commands in my vimrc to a custom colorscheme (named after myself) that selects between two different sets of highlights based on the value of the background option.  Following the advice in $VIMRUNTIME/colors/README.txt, I put the following commands at the start of the colorscheme file:
highlight clear Normal
set bg&
highlight clear

if exists("syntax_on")
    syntax reset
endif

let g:colors_name="jwodder"

and I put colorscheme jwodder at the end of my vimrc.
This worked properly when using a dark-on-light terminal, but when I switched to a light-on-dark terminal, the text ended up using the highlights for "light", and set bg? showed background=light.  If I commented out the colorscheme jwodder line, background ended up set correctly, but then I didn't have my custom colors.  Moving the colorscheme jwodder command to ~/.vim/after/syntax/syncolor.vim (the previous location for my custom highlights) turned the colorscheme back on, but bg was still light on dark terminals.
I then took a look at some of the colorschemes bundled with Vim that query background, such as lunaperche.  None of them do set bg& (nor even the hi clear Normal before it), and removing that line from my colorscheme resulted in everything seemingly working correctly.
However, now I'm confused by the conflicting information from Vim about whether set bg& should be included in a bg-querying colorscheme.  If it should be included, was I calling colorscheme jwodder in the wrong way or in the wrong place?  If it shouldn't be included, why does the README.txt advise including it?

What set bg& does is explained under :help 'background':
When setting 'background' to the default value with:
    :set background&
Vim will guess the value.  In the GUI this should work correctly,
in other cases Vim might not be able to guess the right value.
If the GUI supports a dark theme, you can use the "d" flag in
'guioptions', see 'go-d'.

In other words, that trick is as unreliable as it gets and should not be used.
That document is very old and largely outdated. We barely touched it as part of our remake project because the rest had been exhausting. I just opened an issue for re-examining it.
In the mean time, we strongly recommend you use colortemplate to build your colorscheme. That's the tool we used to build all the colorschemes now distributed with Vim except default.

The line:
set background&

resets the background option to its default.
I would not add that line to the colorscheme but let the caller set it depending on the colors of its terminal.
